# Keras update N batches

Tags: neural-network, keras

I am creating a specialized network with Keras where the batchsize is an important fixed variable representing the size of inputs that get compared. Due to this that makes the update that happen after every batch apply to just 1 example (of size N). Is there a way to update after X batches rather than after every batch?